# List выдаёт out of range (index)

Tags: c#, unity3d

После первого прогона скрипта (т.е после того как лист очищается) получаю ArgumentOutOfRange
В строчке newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];
Искренне не понимаю почему - ведь ситуация полностью эквивалентна и по идее скрипт вообще не должен исполняться (ведь после List.Clear() List.Count по идее должен быть =0, но он почему то не обнуляется даже если я делаю List =null)

```html
void WaitLine()
    {

        if (achiveList!=null&& achiveList.Count !=0 && noOneInWaitLine == false)
        {
            Debug.Log(achiveList.Count);
            newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];

            if (showFinished == true)
            {
                

                if (curTime == 0)
                {
                    curTime = Time.time; // Pause over the Waypoint
                }
                if ((Time.time - curTime) >= 3f && achiveList.Count != currentAchive)
                {
                    currentAchive++;
                    curTime = 0;
                    Debug.Log("Timer Finished");
                    showFinished = false;
                    
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ShowAchiv(newAchiveNumber);
                showFinished = true;
                if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)
                {
                    achiveList.Clear();
                    
                    currentAchive = 0;
                    
                    noOneInWaitLine = true;
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Выполнение строки

```
newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];
```

никак не защищено от случая, когда `currentAchive` равен или больше, чем `achiveList.Count`, что, вероятно, и происходит после очередного увеличения `currentAchive`:

```
if ((Time.time - curTime) >= 3f && achiveList.Count != currentAchive)
{
  currentAchive++;
  curTime = 0;
  Debug.Log("Timer Finished");
  showFinished = false;
}
```

Вы, может быть, думаете, что блок

```
if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)
{
  achiveList.Clear();
  currentAchive = 0;
  noOneInWaitLine = true;
}
```

это поймает, но он не выполнится в том вызове `WaitLine`, в котором `currentAchive` достигнет значения `achiveList.Count`, а в следующем вызове - произойдет ошибка.

*Update*

> И разве achiveList.Count не должен стать 0 после achiveList.Clear();

Должен, конечно. Вот Вам работающий вариант. Проанализируйте, чем он отличается от Вашего.

```
void WaitLine()
{
  if (achiveList != null && achiveList.Count != 0 && !noOneInWaitLine)
  {
    Debug.Log(achiveList.Count);
    newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];

    if (showFinished)
    {
      if (curTime == 0)
      {
        curTime = Time.time; // Pause over the Waypoint
      }
      if ((Time.time - curTime) >= 3f && achiveList.Count != currentAchive)
      {
        currentAchive++;
        curTime = 0;
        Debug.Log("Timer Finished");
        showFinished = false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      ShowAchiv(newAchiveNumber);
      showFinished = true;
    }

    if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)
    {
      achiveList.Clear();
      currentAchive = 0;
      noOneInWaitLine = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Я попробовал ввести проверкуif  currentAchive <= achiveList.Count)
              не помогло к сожалению

Comment: И разве achiveList.Count не должен стать 0 после achiveList.Clear();